# How to "fresh-clean" OS on the server?

Tags: command-line, debian, centos

Is there any fast and reliable way to remove everything not related to OS from the server?

In removing everything I mean:

1. Completely delete all packages and it's dependencies
2. Completely delete all directories not related to OS

In general I'm interested to do this thing on Debian and CentOS based servers.

If there's no a "fast and reliable" way to do it with one or several commands, then please explain how to do it manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're trying to go back to a clean system, as in "fresh install", you need to do a fresh install. Or if you were prescient enough to bare-metal image the system immediately after install, you could go back to that.

Even with Linux's package systems there are configurations and settings that may not be removed in a remove or uninstall. Especially in a server environment, when you need a clean install you cannot simply remove everything you did since the install. You have to cleanly install to get to a clean install state.

**UPDATE: Cleaning packages**

Ramii.org has some tips for listing packages and cleaning unused packages in a debian system: http://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Debian-apt-get-dpkg-packages-cleanup-commands.html

To list the installed packages:

```
dpkg --get-selections | cut -f1 | while read pkg; do dpkg -L $pkg | xargs -I'{}' bash -c 'if [ ! -d "{}" ]; then echo "{}"; fi' | tr '\n' '\000' | du -c --files0-from - | tail -1 | sed "s/total/$pkg/"; done | sort -rn > ~/packages.log.txt
```

He goes on to list methods of listing config files not removed during apt remove processes.

Once you've removed all the packages you wish, run:

```
apt-get autoremove
```

and

```
apt-get clean
```

to clean the repositories and unused apt files.

Comment: I appreciate your help... What's the solution from the solution when you're given root access an virtual server with full of useless stuff?

Comment: If this will be just a playground and not a critical system, you can go through and "aptitude purge" for each package you consider useless. But I must reiterate, this is only a usable method if this system is a playground. Even a test system must be standardized. And a virtual server should be really, really, really easy to reinstall a clean OS on.

Comment: Also, once you've removed the detritus, remember to run the various cleanup arguments of aptitude.

Comment: Thank You! I don't think I can get a better answer... :)

Answer (score 1):

If you remove packages one by one since there is no easy way to do so, make sure to "purge" them. That is, if you are in Debian, "aptitude purge packaged" to remove all configuration files. Then there is also "aptitude autoremove" to remove unnecessary dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

On Debian, you can use the 'deborphan' tool to list packages that have no packages depending on them, so they often can be removed unless you really know you need them. As with all packaging tools: use with caution.